# Record Notability Notes with AirPods Pro to iPad Pro (and/or Mac)?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ipados

I live in a studio apartment with my boyfriend who often works really late. He gets home at 3am and needs to get quality rest. The problem is I need to attend all of my online classes in-person at 8 am in the morning. I really want to be able to record the lectures on Notability (so that I can play them back later in a way the is connected the the timing of the note modifying) while using Notability on my iPad Pro.

I’m viewing the lecture on my MacBook, but if it makes the solution easier I can also enter the lecture (Zoom) on my iPad Pro.

Comment: I’ll assume your lecturer isn’t using notability to lecture - https://support.gingerlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040604772-Tips-for-Online-Learning-with-Notability and focus on what you can record from Zoom on macOS and iPadOS.

Comment: Or you could use headphones...? I guess you won't be speaking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked your lecturer to record the lectures so you might review them later?

- https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362473-Local-recording

If they won’t, perhaps they would let you record it on your MacBook. This might be easier than using iOS screen recording.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207935

We record town halls on the presenter side and it works great for playback later. No one needs to handle it on the attendance side.

Last option, macOS can record the screen and your voice easily from AirPods or any other speaker / microphone combination.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721

You would need help if you wanted to loop the meeting audio into the recording.

- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/

There is an [academic discount for Sound Source](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=MiscEducationalDiscounts) if you decide it helps you after testing the free trial to keep the sound low while you study and learn.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn’t solve my problem. 
I want to record while writing on my Notability so the recording is connected to the notes themselves (that way I can click on a line I wrote and it immediately plays the part of the lecture when I wrote that line down). 
For that purpose any recording that’s not connected to Notability isn’t helping

Answer (score 0):

I use the Quicktime screen recording feature combined with Soundflower, which is a program that allows you to internally route audio via “virtual audio cables” (file paths) from your computer's system output to recording software. Soundflower creates a virtual “audio device” on your machine that your audio system can see. That will allow you to reroute the output of the computer as a microphone. You won't be able to hear anything during the class but it will record all the sounds from the system together with the screen.

After installing the plugin, you will be able to output the sound of your system like this:

[image]

When you open the Quicktime Screen Recording, select the Soundflower as a microphone:

[image]

So the system will output all sounds to the input, and Quicktime will record video & audio from whatever you do. However you won't be able to hear anything while the output is routed. Use your iPad instead.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain how this works if I need my iPad to record what I’m hearing on my AirPods? 
I believe it means that I should connect the AirPods to the iPad and listen to the lecture with the iPad. I don’t think I found Soundflower for iOS

Comment: @MiritHadas I am editing my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I still don’t quite understand how my iPad (which is the recording device) will get that input. 
If I got it right what you said will work well for Mac, but I need this to be on my iPad.. any ideas?

Comment: @MiritHadas no, it only works for OSX. You should do everything on the computer, just use the iPad to listen. Later you will have the video with audio and whatever notes you did.

Comment: So I don’t think I fully explained the problem. 
I have to use my iPad, that’s the whole purpose. 
I’m using notability which a note app that has a feature that can record what the iPad “hears” and link the timing of what I write on the app to the recording. 
That way when I click on a line I start to hear what was recorded when I wrote that line. 
I need a solution on how to do this when I hear the lecture through my AirPods

Comment: Let me get this straight: the app has to "hear" it out loud for you to record it? BUT you also don't want to wake your boyfriend up? I am afraid you will have to choose.

Comment: The app has to hear it either out loud or through the headphones’ microphone

Comment: @MiritHadas sorry I think you are asking too much. You could either record the video silent and watch it later with Notability on; or (my personal choice), give up the app and use the computer to do everything. If you take notes on text edit they will be also recorded at the same time with the video.